# How to get values by key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

Is there any nifty way to get values from an array of hashes:

```
var foo = {a: "aFirst", b: "bFirst", c: "cFirst"};
var boo = {a: "aSecond", b: "bSecond", c: "cSecond"};
var bar = {a: "aThird", b: "bThird", c: "cThird"};
var myArrOfHashes = [foo, boo, bar];
```

So I would expect something like:

```
myArrOfHashes.map(b) // => bFirst, aSecond, aThird
```

Comment: sorry but this line isn't clear to me (`myArrOfHashes.map(b) // => bFirst, aSecond, aThird`) can you elaborate more plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not quite like that, but you could try this:

```
myArrOfHashes.map(function(hash){ return hash.b; });
```

Comment: Note it's ES5 only, that means no IE8, but there are polyfills.

Comment: @DanMyasnikov don't forget to accept an answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: I wasn't able to, as there is a time limit.

Done, mate!

Answer (score 4):

One easy way to do this - and many similar things - is with the [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) libraries.

Here's an example from the [Lo-Dash documentation](http://lodash.com/docs#pluck):

```
var stooges = [
    { 'name': 'moe', 'age': 40 },
    { 'name': 'larry', 'age': 50 }
];

_.pluck(stooges, 'name');
// → ['moe', 'larry']
```

Even if you use a different approach for this particular problem, you should definitely check out these libraries. (They are very similar to each other; between the two I prefer Lo-Dash.)

Comment: thanks for suggesting some frameworks, however I use Sencha Touch

Comment: What is lo_dash? Is that a ripoff of underscore?

Comment: @DanMyasnikov you can use both at the same time. underscore is a library (a pretty good one), not a framework

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's sort of what Zepto is to jQuery. They do the same thing but in different ways. I think lodash has some more features tho.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Lo-Dash is not a ripoff, it's a fork of Underscore. The [Lo-Dash home page](http://lodash.com/) has information about the difference between the two libraries, with a lot of detail in [this blog post](http://kitcambridge.be/blog/say-hello-to-lo-dash/).

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but try

```
var map = function(key) {
  return function(value) {
    return value[key];
  };
};

console.log(myArrOfHashes.map(map('b')));
```